# Absolutely cannot run any macro after SetTimer function is used

Tags: vba, excel, winapi

So I need to use the SetTimer API in my Excel VB project, but after I execute the interval timer, the program crashes as soon as you attempt to run another macro. Even when simply clicking the macro button in Developer tab. The code:

```
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public timId As Long, lala As Long, i As Integer

Public Sub CallTm()

timId = SetTimer(0, 0, 100, AddressOf Test)

End Sub
Public Sub AnotherSub()

MsgBox "This is not gonna be shown"

End Sub

Public Sub Test()

Cells(1, 1).Value = i
i = i + 1

End Sub
```

It seems it's not a problem with KillTimer. Simply setting the interval with SetTimer is like a switch for making sure no more macros can be run (or it will simply crash if you attempt that). I remember seeing *Error 50290* if that's any more help.

Why is it so and how can it be fixed?

By the way, I'm making a snake game in Excel for a school project.

It seems like after the Timer is set, nothing can happen since the timer takes up all the thread? or smth like that and it can't be "interrupted".

Really, how is this API supposed to be used? It seems like a fatal error which makes it completely useless...

Comment: Timer procedures need to have a certain function signature. No idea how to declare that in Excel, but you can see the signature in the docs for the [TimerProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644907).

Comment: Nevermind, thank you ^, I played around with the TimerProc function and wow it works! It seems that you need to pass the SetTimer arguments to the function to be executed in intervals, the callback function in other words.  Vital but overlooked information in many places I saw online.

Answer (score 1):

You're corrupting the stack, because your `Test` procedure does not match the signature of [TimerProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You should read and understand the documentation for API calls before simply making a blind stab at using them.

You can find the documentation for [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN as well, just like all other WinAPI documentation.

Answer (score 1):

the prototype of timerPorc is this

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(
  _In_ HWND     hwnd,
  _In_ UINT     uMsg,
  _In_ UINT_PTR idEvent,
  _In_ DWORD    dwTime
);
```

that can be translated to vb as follow

```
sub Test(byval hWnd as long, byval uMsg as long,byval idIvent as long, byval dwTime as long)

    'your code here

end sub
```