# ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll not working when called from timer sub

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, refresh

[Edit:] Fixed code tags [/Edit]

I set up a timer (code adapted from various sources). 
It calls one sub, which contains the line ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
If I run the sub RefreshData by hitting F5 from within it, it works fine.
If I call the sub from within the Timer sub, I get Run-time Error 50290

The data includes various queries to an SQL server database.

The code:

Tried adding DoEvents after, no go. Same error.

```
Sub Timer()

Dim TimeOut As Long
'Set Timeout in minutes
TimeOut = 5

If blnTimer Then

    lngTimerID = KillTimer(0, lngTimerID)

    If lngTimerID = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Error: Timer Not Stopped"

        Exit Sub

    End If

    Debug.Print "blnTimer = False"
    blnTimer = False

Else

    lngTimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, TimeSerial(0, TimeOut, 0), AddressOf RefreshData)

    If lngTimerID = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Error: Timer Not Generated"

        Exit Sub

    End If
    Debug.Print "blnTimer = True"
    blnTimer = True

End If

Debug.Print "Timer Complete at " & Time

End Sub

Sub RefreshData()

'Refresh all data connections
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Complete all refresh events before moving on
DoEvents

Debug.Print "Data Refreshed at " & Time

End Sub
```

Expected result is every 5 minutes the sub RefreshData will be called, which will run the command ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll and update all external data connections.

[Edit:] Update - I just tried doing an Application.CalculateFullRebuild (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867158/macro-to-refresh-an-entire-excel-workbookall-data-connections-and-calculations)) just above the RefreshAll, and the same error code appears on the CalculateFullRebuild line. The plot thickens...

[Edit 2] I will post my full solution, because I then limited it to our office hours and that might be useful for someone who finds this post as well. Credit to @EvR for the Application.OnTime help! 
NOTE: The code below must be in ThisWorkbook and the module you want to run must either be in Module1 or you must change Module1 to where your code is - and of course change the name of the Sub from RefreshData to your sub, both in the start timer and end timer subs below...

[Edit3]: I forgot to include the Public variable declaration for MyTime - if you don't use it as a public variable (i.e. outside any subroutine) then the Cancel routine (ThisWorkbook_BeforeClose) won't work and you'll get an error each time you close the workbook: it needs the exact MyTime value to cancel the timer.

[Edit4]: Should be if timer >= officecloses - otherwise it will set Seconds = 0 when the hour is 17:00... And it won't run again until the workbook opens again manually! Below code updated.

[Edit5]: Seconds needs to be Long type because when I do the sum for overnight, there's not enough memory in an integer for the large number of seconds needed! Code updated below.

[Edit6]: I just discovered that you can't add 23 hours to the current time (makes sense when you think about it - date drops back to Excel's first date). I needed to add DateAdd("d", 1, MyTime) and change my initial setting of MyTime to use Now instead of Time (Now includes both time and date). Yes I have manually opened it each morning since this to find the memory error, and ok'd, closed and opened manually... Until today. Today is a new day!! :D Corrected code below.

```
Public Dim MyTime As Date

Sub RefreshOnTime()

Dim Delay As Integer
Dim OfficeOpens As Integer
Dim OfficeCloses As Integer
Dim Overnight As Integer
Dim DayAdvance As Integer

'Delay in seconds
Delay = 240
'hour of opening
OfficeOpens = 7
'hour of closing (24hr clock)
OfficeCloses = 17

'If in working hours
If Hour(Time) >= OfficeOpens And Hour(Time) < OfficeCloses Then
    Overnight = 0
    DayAdvance = 0
'If in the morning (e.g. auto open after scheduled reboot at 3am)
ElseIf Hour(Time) < OfficeOpens Then
    Overnight = (OfficeOpens - Hour(Time))
    DayAdvance = 0
'If after 5pm add 1 to day
'Add morning hours
ElseIf Hour(Time) >= OfficeCloses Then
    Overnight = (OfficeOpens - Hour(Time))
    DayAdvance = 1
End If

Debug.Print "Hours = " & Overnight

'Add Seconds to current time
MyTime = DateAdd("s", Delay, Now)
Debug.Print "MyTime after adding Seconds = " & MyTime

'Add DayAdvance to MyTime
MyTime = DateAdd("d", DayAdvance, MyTime)
Debug.Print "MyTime after adding DayAdvance = " & MyTime

'Add Overnight to MyTime
MyTime = DateAdd("h", Overnight, MyTime)

Debug.Print "RefreshData will run at " & MyTime

'REPLACE MODULE1 with the right module
'REPLACE RefreshData with the name of your sub
Application.OnTime MyTime, "Module1.RefreshData"

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

'REPLACE MODULE1 with the right module
'REPLACE RefreshData with the name of your sub
Application.OnTime MyTime, "Thisworkbook.RefreshData", , False

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Just in case you need to debug
'Uncomment these 3 lines and click "No" on workbook open
'Dim Ans As Variant
'Ans = MsgBox("Do you want to run RefreshOnTime?", vbYesNo, "Yes/No")
'If Ans = vbYes Then RefreshOnTime

RefreshOnTime

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you alternatively tried to reference to the workbook name or index, instead of the active workbook?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook` is not recommended. This is because you could have a workbook open at the time your code is run which is not the workbook you want to reference. Qualify your workbook

Comment: Thank you both! I tried ThisWorkbook as well, but worth a go using Application.Workbooks("NAMEOFWB").RefreshAll

Comment: Nope, same error with that...

Comment: Data that you are trying to refresh, is it in the same workbook where your UDF is? Tip: when refereeing to someone here, include **@** sign infront of there name so they get a notification when you respond to them

Comment: Does this thread help you:? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964412/absolutely-cannot-run-any-macro-after-settimer-function-is-used

Comment: Thanks @Zac Will do, and the data is not in the same workbook it's queries to an SQL Server.

Comment: @EvR Thank you, I don't understand the technicals on that post, but I can say that the call to RefreshData works, and I can call another Sub from the sub RefreshData successfully, so it's not a problem with calling other subs once the timer is set as the question on that post said.. Am I missing something there?

Comment: @jfgoodhew1 yes, when the timer is set, do you need this API? Or could you do with the 'normal' application.ontime?

Comment: @EvR I'm not really sure how to use application.ontime - I cobbled the above together trying things from different sites, and stopping when it worked :) The end game is the whole procedure running every 5 minutes until stopped, and that includes saving as an Excel 2003 file, reopening the original file with macros, refreshing an Access database table connection to the 2003 file just created and closing the 2003 file :) Most of it is done now, but if Application.OnTime can do that (maybe in ThisWorkbook.Open routine?) that may be better still... Can you give me an example of application.ontime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your timer-sub with this code in the ThisWorkbook-section:

```
Dim MyTime As Date

Sub RefreshOnTime()
RefreshData
MyTime = DateAdd("s", 500, Time)
Application.OnTime MyTime, "Thisworkbook.RefreshOnTime"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.OnTime MyTime, "Thisworkbook.RefreshOnTime", , False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
RefreshOnTime
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much EvR your code is so clear it barely needs comments! Only thing is I don't technically close the xlsm workbook: it's saved as a xls instead (necessary for 3rd party app still using JET driver). So, the timer never ceases... And, the penultimate operation of RefreshData is to open the xlsm up again - so it ends up tripping over itself... I've amended it so the timer calls "Module1.RefreshData" instead of running it in the first of your ThisWorkbook sub, and job done :D Thanks a million.